# How to set-up Docker container and Dockerfile with php-apache and python?

Tags: python, php, docker

I am attempting to set-up a docker container with php-apache and python. This is primarily for a php web application. For part of the functionality I wrote a python script that is utilizing a python library which fulfills functionality that I couldn't find with php. Otherwise I'd have just tried to stick to php for everything. I run the python script with php's shell_exec command. Everything works in my local development environment; however, when I attempt to push to production problems arise. Anyways, I have been trying for hours (tons of research on the topic) and I cannot figure out how to get Python installed on the same Docker container as php-apache. Here is an example of a Dockerfile I've been using:

```
    FROM python:3.7
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install python3.7
    COPY requirements.txt ./
    RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    FROM php:7.4.13-apache
    RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
```

With this set-up I get "sh: 1: python: not found".

If I remove the last two lines (php-apache) the container keeps restarting continuously (though python is installed in this case). I've tried many other examples of dockerfiles for python and combined with php-apache none have worked.

Comment: You probably want two separate containers, one built `FROM php:apache` and one built `FROM python`.  A simple Flask wrapper around the script will make it possible to communicate from one container to the other.  There's no way to combine the two base images.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am attempting as you suggested to build two containers, one for php:apache, and one for python. I have both containers set up; however, the python container simply downloads requirements then displays "exited with code 0". Is this where flask can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the suggestion from @DavidMaze and setting up two separate containers, one for php:apache, and one for python. For the python container I built a simple flask application with endpoints that, when a GET request is made, run a specific python function. I used PHP curl to communicate with this flask api from the php:apache container.